# Need input: Palindrome in Python

Tags: python, palindrome

```
paliList=[1,3,2,5,5,6,2,3,1]
listlen=len(paliList)
hallist=int(l/2)
i=0
c=0
while(a):
    while(c<=a):
        while(l>i):
            while(paliList[i]==paliList[l-1]):
                i+=1
                l-=1
        print('List is not palindrome')
        c+=1
```

Hi, above is my piece of code to find whether the list is Palindrome (rather elements in the list are in palindrome). I have having difficulty printing the message 'List is not palindrome'. I tried printing this message here and there but not able to conclude.

Comment: You could simply do:

    s = 'racecar'
    print 'is palindrome', s==s.reverse()

Comment: Why are you using `while` loops here at all? Is this homework? There are better ways to check for palindromes otherwise

Comment: `if paliList == paliList[::-1]: print("List is palindrome")`

Comment: @HughBothwell Awesome trick! Why didn't it trick me ..Thanks!

Comment: @AdamHughes not working. I just tried to use this piece of code:s=[1,3,3,1]
if s == s.reverse():
    print('this is palindrome')
else:
    print('this is not palindrome')

Comment: @JohnLaRooy-AKAgnibbler yeah came to know now those ways!

Comment: Sorry, didn't have a chance to test it.  Hugh nailed it.

Answer (score 4):

For any iterable, you can check if it's a palindrome by doing:

```
all(i==j for i,j in zip(some_iter, reversed(some_iter)))
```

For any object that supports slicing, you can do:

```
some_iter == some_iter[::-1]
```

Comment: what is some_inter? Did you create this function?

Comment: Sorry.. pls ignore above comment.what is zip? User-defined function? What is i, i?

Comment: @brilliant `some_iter` is any iterable. Anything you could do `for element in some_iter` on. Lists, strings, tuples, etc

Comment: @brilliant `zip` is a builtin that combines two iterables